# Using aquillian to test jax-rs - do I need a servlet?

Tags: ejb, jax-rs, resteasy, jboss-arquillian

I'm testing my jax-rs services using aquillian and the wildfly embeded container. In this setup, I'm trying to understand how my web services are handled by the server. To set things up, I have the following deployment in my test:

```
@Deployment
    public static WebArchive create() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "rest-service.war")
                .addClasses(ProfileService.class,
                        Profile.class); // classes and other resources into the war
    }
```

So that war gets deployed and its running in an embedable container. However, my test can't find a service at any of the URLs mapped in `ProfileService`. Is it because my war is missing a servlet? Specifically, a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` instance? Or am I misunderstanding how EJB containers expose jax-rs services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you're missing a class that extends `Application`, however you don't need to register it as a servlet.  As long as its annotated `@ApplicationPath` it will be picked up by the container.